# Rails: How to add Validations for wrong dates eg November 31 and June 31. Ihave used :date as my column type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form that looks like this
views/profiles/_form

```
<div class="field2">
<%= f.label :purchase_date, "Date this horse was purchased" %><br />
<%= f.date_select :purchase_date %>
</div>

<div class="field2">
<%= f.label :owner_name, "Owner Name" %><br />
<%= f.text_field :owner_name %>
 </div>
```

what validation do i add in my model/profile.rb

validates :purchase_date ????????

Comment: you can use jquery or html5 datepicker very easily.

Comment: @MuhamamdAwais: But those won't help with server-side validation and if you're not doing server-side validation then you're doing it all wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [exclusion validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#exclusion). It looks like this:

```
# Made it a constant, but could also be in a method.
EXCLUSION_DATE = [Date.new(2012,1,1), Date.new(2012,2,1)]
validates :purchase_date, :exclusion => { :in => EXCLUSION_DATES }
```

You can also always add your own custom validations:

```
validate :check_purchase_date # Name it whatever you want

private
  def check_purchase_date
    exclusion_dates = [Date.new(2012,1,1), Date.new(2012,2,1)]
    if exclusion_dates.include?(self.purchase_date)
      self.errors.add(:purchase_date, "cannot be on a reserved date.")
    end
  end
```

Comment: Your code definitely works. Is there a way I can do it for multiple date columns with out having to repeat the same code for each column. Basically I am saying I want the validation to do it for more than one column. for example :purchase_date and :vaccination_date

Answer (score 0):

why not let the user select from jquery datepicker for example, so that you can eliminate tje problem straightaway?

Comment: What if someone sends a POST directly to the update URL, or has JS blocked and enters in any date?